# Dart list item not found

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a list of map of antigens(elements) and added some antigens into another list i.e. selected. I want the color of the list item to be red if it is contained in the selected list.
But it doesn't show color change even on printing the selected items the antigen is present there.

```
import 'package:allerpath_app_new/controller/mulit_allergy_profile_controller.dart';
import 'package:allerpath_app_new/model/blood_antigens.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get_instance/src/extension_instance.dart';

class TestingMAP extends StatelessWidget {
  TestingMAP({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final controller = Get.put(MultiProfile());

  final BloodAntigens antigen = BloodAntigens();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<dynamic> _namesList =
        controller.selectedAntigens.map((e) => e['name']).toList();
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: antigen.inhalantPanel.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var item = antigen.inhalantPanel[index];
          return Text(
            item['name'],
            style: TextStyle(
              color: (_namesList.contains(item)) ? Colors.red : Colors.black,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

I printed the list and if it is present or not

```
print(controller.selectedAntigens);
print((controller.selectedAntigens.contains(item)) ? '1' : '0');
```

**Output:**

```
[{name: STRAW DUST, value: 123}]
0
```

**Model code**

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> inhalantPanel = [
    {'name': 'HOUSE DUST', 'value': 0.35},
    {'name': 'MIXED MITES', 'value': 0.35},
    {'name': 'COCKROACH', 'value': 0.35},
    {'name': 'STRAW DUST', 'value': 0.35},
    {'name': 'COTTON', 'value': 0.35},
    {'name': 'JUTE', 'value': 0.35},
  ];
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the entire widgets source code.  It may be as simple as not using a StatefulWidget but I can't tell from the limited code.

Comment: I've updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you probably don't have equality operators in your model of antigens.

You either do that, or create a list containing the names of antigens for example.

```
List<String> _namesList = controller.selectedAntigens.map((e)=>e['name']).toList();

print(_namesList.contains(item['name']) ? '1' : '0'); //=> "1";
```

Comment: This throws an error: The instance member 'controller' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression.

Comment: How to handle it?

Comment: And what do you mean by I don't have equality operator in model of antigens.

Comment: Put the code I posted directly under your `Widget build`, before `return`, it'll work. Regarding equlity, you can easily say if a String == anotherString. But for lists or maps, look into dart's package called `collection`. Which compares deeply nested lists and maps.

Comment: I've fixed the error but still the UI doesn't reflect changes as intended

Comment: Then there is something else in your code.

Comment: I've posted the complete UI file please take a review.

Comment: You posted my answer wrong, in color, you need to use `item['name']`, like this: `color: (_namesList.contains(item['name']))` . It will work.

Comment: Thankyou so much. It worked. This had screwed me up for 2 days now. Thanks

Comment: You are most welcome! Take a look at equality operators though, it's the cleaner way to do things, this is sloppy. If it helped you out, please consider voting and marking it as an answer to your post. Happy coding! :-)